# React: function return before fetch finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, fetch

When i call the function ShowUserPanel() i also call the getUsers function that gives me the data that i have to insert in the var rows that is necessary to populate the table. The problem is that the ShowUserPanel function return the empty table without the data, but if i go to another page and comeback the table is populated, i don't know how to populate the table at the call of the funciton.

```js
function createData(name, surname, username, email) {
    return { name, surname, username, email };
}

var rows = []

function getUsers(_callback) {
    fetch(conn, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: localStorage.getItem("username"),
        })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            var name = new Array(responseJson[0]);
            var surname = new Array(responseJson[1]);
            var username = new Array(responseJson[2]);
            var email = new Array(responseJson[3]);
            var count = name[0]['length'];
            var temp = new Array();
            var i = 0;
            while (i <= count) {
                temp.push(createData(name[0][i], surname[0][i], username[0][i], email[0][i]));
                i++;
            }
            rows = temp;
            _callback();
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.toString());
    });
}

export default function ShowUserPanel() {
    getUsers(function () {
        console.log('finish');
    });
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
            <div>
                <h1>SHOW USERS</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <UserButtonList/>
            </div>
            <div style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                display: 'felx',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <Card style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    marginTop: '10px',
                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                    color: 'white'
                }}>
                    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
                        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <StyledTableCell align="center">NAME</StyledTableCell>
                                    <StyledTableCell align="center">SURNAME</StyledTableCell>
                                    <StyledTableCell align="center">USERNAME</StyledTableCell>
                                    <StyledTableCell align="center">EMAIL</StyledTableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody>
                                {rows.map((row) => (
                                    <StyledTableRow key={row.name}>
                                        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row" align="center">
                                            {row.name}
                                        </StyledTableCell>
                                        <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.surname}</StyledTableCell>
                                        <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.username}</StyledTableCell>
                                        <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.email}</StyledTableCell>
                                    </StyledTableRow>
                                ))}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
                </Card>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Use useEffect hook along with useState to make it more like actual react component. Right now, there's no life-cycle in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `useEffect` for the function call and use a state to keep `rows` data like this:

```
function createData(name, surname, username, email) {
  return { name, surname, username, email };
}

export default function ShowUserPanel() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]); // <-- Add [] as default value

  useEffect(() => {
    function getUsers(_callback) {
      fetch(conn, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: localStorage.getItem("username")
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          var name = new Array(responseJson[0]);
          var surname = new Array(responseJson[1]);
          var username = new Array(responseJson[2]);
          var email = new Array(responseJson[3]);
          var count = name[0]["length"];
          var temp = new Array();
          var i = 0;
          while (i <= count) {
            temp.push(
              createData(name[0][i], surname[0][i], username[0][i], email[0][i])
            );
            i++;
          }
          setRows(temp);
          _callback();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error.toString());
        });
    };

    getUsers(function() {
      console.log("finish");
    });

  }, []);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <div>Your HTML</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried it but  how can i use them in this code: {rows((row) => (
                          <StyledTableRow key={row.name}>
                          <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row" align="center">
                              {row.name}
                          </StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.surname}</StyledTableCell>
                          <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.username}</StyledTableCell>              Becuase it show me that he cannot read property map

Comment: you can use curly braces ```[]``` as your state default value

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Issue :**

You are updating `rows` variable , and it is being updated but react doesn't care about it, for re rendering if you want to re-render the component you can make use of `state` and any change on that will cause the re-render, that's why you are not getting updated dom on first time, but when you get back to this page there is already data loaded from previous request you made, so It will display it.

---

**Solution :**

Here you go, you can do something like this with the help of `useState` and `useEffect`, please do read comments , hope that will make all things clear to you

```
// var rows = [] // <----- Remove this

function getUsers(_callback){
    fetch(conn, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username: localStorage.getItem("username"),
            })

            }).then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                var name = new Array(responseJson[0]);
                var surname = new Array(responseJson[1]);
                var username = new Array(responseJson[2]);
                var email = new Array(responseJson[3]);
                var count = name[0]['length'];
                var temp = new Array();
                var i = 0;
                while(i <= count){
                    temp.push(createData(name[0][i], surname[0][i], username[0][i], email[0][i]));
                    i++;
                }
                rows = temp; 
                _callback(rows); // <----------- HERE, passing back data
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error.toString());
                });
}

export default function ShowUserPanel() {

    const [rows,setRows] = useState([]) // <----- We'll need state to re-render

    useEffect(() => { // <----- Need useEffect for lifecycle hooks
        getUsers(function(rowsData){ // <----- getting data back from function to set state and re-render with it
            console.log('finish');
            setRows(rowsData); // <----- Setting up state, so react will know to re render
        });
    },[]); // <----- HERE, for once time load only ( on mount only )

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```